# Razor pages Microsoft identity is logging off user after minutes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, logout

I'm developing Razor pages application and using microsoft identity. The problem is when I log in and keep inactive for about 20-30 minutes application will log me off. By inactive I mean server inactive. For instance I have to fill huge form which I will be filling for hour. But when I press save. It wont save, it will redirect me to login page. But if I fill it in few minutes everything is ok. Can anyone help me ? Is there some settings in startup I'm missing?
Sorry if it's some trivial question. But I cant find anything regarding this problem.

startup:

```
namespace WorkersManager
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                //options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Privacy");
                //options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Workers");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
            });
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = 1500;
            });
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            });
            services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ValueCountLimit = 8000; // 200 items max
                //options.ValueLengthLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100MB max len form data

            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
                     policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
                options.AddPolicy("RequireUserRole",
                     policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));


            });
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>////WorkersManagerrContext
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WorkersManagerrContext")));
            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            //        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(10));

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();





            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share how do you set up the session in Startup,cs. There should be a setting that you can set a Timeout for the session. Please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @arunes, added my startup to the question. I do not have any explicit settings for sessions is that the problem?